# PHP Character Encoding

Tags: php, text, unicode, encode, sanitization

I've created an inventory system in PHP that's used across North America so some users may have different character encoding (perhaps in Canada). The "Inventory Description" field (`$_POST['InvDesc']`) is converted to UTF-8 to keep things standardized before inserting into a database:

```
iconv("Windows-1251", "UTF-8", $_POST["InvDesc"])
```

For some odd reason, one of my user's submitted a description with apostrophes and the string output to this:

> I??™ve made the purchase but I don??™t have the receipt.

Any idea where my method of standardizing text is at fault? Thanks!

Comment: Are you storing data in a database? What is your database's collation?

Comment: Are you sure they're apostrophes? There are various characters that look like apostrophes.

Comment: Might be the curly single quotes. Also, is your HTML setup to have utf-8 as the enctype?

Comment: Try to use `iconv("Windows-1251", "UTF-8", $_POST["InvDesc"]), PHP_EOL;`

Comment: It looks like you're assuming that posted data is Windows-1251 which is probably not the case.

Comment: @MehdiBounya DB Collation is SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS.

Comment: @IncredibleHat Yes.

Comment: @Nick No effect.

Comment: Use UTF-8 collation in your database

Comment: @Olivier  I am running on a Windows environment (ISS) that has PHP. – theflarenet 11 secs ago

Comment: Ok, if your html is set to utf-8, then incoming is in utf-8. You are wanting to convert TO Windows-1251? Then your iconv is backwards.

Comment: @theflarenet regarding conveting to SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS, you'll probably want to look at this answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/10143652/729440