# How Encode SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS

Tags: php, sql-server, encoding

I readed to [Encoding SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS into UTF-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10124930/encoding-sql-latin1-general-cp1-ci-as-into-utf-8). Despite trying all of the writings, it never happened.

I am using php 7.1

Example:

```
$str = iconv('UCS-2LE', 'UTF-8', $str);
$str = iconv('CP1252', 'ISO-8859-1', $str);
$str = iconv('CP850', 'UTF-8//TRANSLIT", $str);
```

Output :

```
䅋䅐ⵋ䙅⁅䅒䥋传䕚⁌䅔䅓䥒⁍䅍呎剁䥌䬠偁䭁
EFEYAÃžÃœZÃœM
KOL├Ø- 70cl S├ØL├ØN.K.x6AD
```

wrong characters appear.In the meantime I am using Turkish characters.

Regards.

Comment: latin1/CP1 is ISO8859-1, and is *not* a turkish encoding scheme. First you need to determine what your source data's encoding *actually is*. The most likely candidates being [ISO-8859-3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-3), [ISO-8859-9](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-9), or [Windows-1254](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1254).

Comment: I connect to another remote server. How can I learn the source character set?